# Topological analogue of an FC group?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, topological-groups

By definition, a group is FC if all its conjugacy classes are finite.

Has anything been published about a generalization of the FC property for topological groups?

Comment: Yes, for locally compact groups check §2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4194 and references therein.

Comment: @YCor Thank you, that's very helpful. I'd be happy to accept this as an answer. At the same time, I am still curious if anyone has looked at other generalizations of the FC property, groups in which conjugacy classes are small in some other sense (meager, measure zero, ...).

Comment: Most interesting non-discrete locally compact groups have conjugacy class whose closure has empty interior and in particular are meager of measure zero. This applies to all non-discrete locally compact abelian groups, all $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ or $\mathrm{SL}_n(K)$ for $K=\mathbf{R},\mathbf{C},\mathbf{Q}_p$, the direct product of any locally compact group with $\mathbf{R}$, etc. So it sounds hopeless to have an analogue of the results about FC-groups under such assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1963, Usakov characterised topological FC groups:

https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=165031

Comment: Also S.P. Wang, "Compactness properties of topological groups", Trans. AMS 154 (1971), 301--314. Also, arxiv.org/abs/1306.4194 and references therein, as pointed out YCor in his comment. In all these sources the _topological_ _FC_ property is the one where conjugacy classes are relatively compact.